# Bootstrap grid column one split into two row, column two adjacent to it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
">"        col1             col2      
">"   |--------------|---------------|
">"   |   text1      |               | 
">"   |--------------|  navigation   | 
">"   |    text2     |               |
">"   |--------------|---------------|
```

I need to create grid like the diagram above to hold texts and navigational menu.
so far I try different variation using row and span.
the idea is col1 split into two and col2 should be next to it.
the column on left split in two, column right same height but adjacent to column one.

```
    `<div class="row">  
            <div class="span6"> 
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue;">AAAA</div>
               </div>       
              <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">BBBB</div>
              </div>    
            </div>  

            <div class="span6">

              <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:yellow;">row2</div>
              </div>

            </div>  
        </div>`
```

Comment: i think you should use col-xs-6 insteat of span6 class

Answer (score 6):

This will help you. [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/r6k51fby/)

I added `background-color` so you could see the `divs`.

Comment: Thank You Green Fox, this answer the question

Comment: ... is not a complete solution but it shows the way around which was sufficient for my task => +1 :-).

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">Text 1</div>
    <div class="span2">Text 2</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   Navigation
</div>
</div>
```